# How to correctly calculate the Dynamic Range of an image

Tags: hdr, image-processing, dynamic-range, calculations

I'm trying to compare the dynamic range of a correctly exposed LDR picture with the dynamic range of the HDR image obtained with 3 LDR pictures.

Right now I'm calculating the DR as:

```
 stops = log2(max) - log2(min);
```

Where

```
max = maximum pixel value found in the image
min = minimum pixel value found in the image
```

The reference correctly exposed image is an 8 bits Jpeg, so the dynamic range is always 8 stops, since the values goes from 0 to 255.
The HDR image is an RGBe radiance map, so the values are 32 bits floating point.

I was wondering a few things:

1. Is this the correct way to calculate the dynamic range from a picture?
2. All jpg files have pixel values from 0 to 255, so every correctly exposed jpg will have the same dynamic range. Is this right?
3. Sometimes the calculated dynamic range of the HDR image is lower than the original. How is this possible?

Thank you for your help

EDIT: adding an image to better explain my reasoning

[image: Left: standard correcly exposed image - Right: HDR image blended from 3 bracketed photos]

Left: standard correcly exposed image - Right: HDR image blended from 3 bracketed photos

Comment: re 2: all jpegs using the full 0..255 range have the same dynamic range but not all real world images have so much dynamic. therefore, no, not every jpeg has the same dynamic range.

Comment: as for 3, this obviously depends on the processing. you can artificially increase or decrease (tonemapping) at will. if, however, the goal of the LDR image stacking is to faithfully represent the real world luminance and the resulting HDR dynamic range is lower than LDR source images then something must have gone wrong.

Comment: In the end, I'd like to calculate how much the dynamic range is increased after the HDR blending. I feel like it should always be greater, but sometimes it's not and many times is just a little bit greater but that's it. I feel like I'm doing something wrong. So I was wondering, how would you guys do it? Because that formula I'm using may be good for calculating the DR of the sensor knowing the noise voltage and the full well capacity voltage, but maybe it's not when you just have pixel values. What would you guys do?

Comment: Do you want to calculate the DR of the contents of the 32-bit floating point file? Or the DR when it is displayed on your screen in 8-bits?

Comment: I'd like to find out how much the LDR file can capture from the scene, and how much more it's possible to capture with an HDR blending. What I'd like to do it's getting the actual dynamic range captured.

Comment: _"The reference correctly exposed image is an 8 bits Jpeg, so the dynamic range is always 8 stops, since the values goes from 0 to 255."_ is an incorrect premise in _several_ ways.

Comment: obviously it can happen that the range of pixel values in a jpg image won't go through al the range from 0 to 255. But at most the DR will be 8 stops.

Comment: anyone, I added a photo to try to explain better the problem

Comment: What am I missing? Using a densitometer take a reading of the lightest and darkest tone on the print and the difference is the dynamic range of the image. Normally, it's about 1.6 to 1.8 (log values) either way. Maybe you could get a 2.0 (1:100).

Comment: I wouldn't take the reading from the print but from the scene, to discover what range of illuminance values I can record before and after the HDR blending process. This would be something to do in a lab so not really straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

First, regardless of the particular dynamic range definition, calculating "anything vs zero" luminance is not useful, because then the ratio becomes infinite. Your:

```
log2(max)-log2(0)
```

is another way of saying:

```
log(max/0)
```

and we can't divide by zero (and log2(0) is undefined)

So let's forget the 0 for now (zero means the image is not well exposed anyway because you can't have any detail at level 0), then, indeed:

```
log2(255)-log2(1) = ~8 (EV)
```

But this is not the dynamic range either, because in JPEG (and sRGB in general) pixel **values** are not pixel **luminance**.

Taking the proper [gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#The_reverse_transformation) formula into account, we finally get:

```
log2(1)-log2(1/3294.6) = ~12 (EV)
```

(See also: [8bit monitor theoretical contrast](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/110418/8bit-monitor-theoretical-contrast))

Comment: yeah obviously I don't do log(0), if the min is 0 I just put 1. Anyway, is 12 EVs the screen dynamic range?

Comment: anyone, I added a photo to try to explain better the problem

Answer (score 2):

The end result of [*High Dynamic Range Imaging (HDRI)*](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/7623/15871) is not to produce an image with dynamic range as high as the scene it attempts to reproduce. We do not have display technology available that can do that. At least not practical ones.

The aim of HDRI is to take a very high dynamic range scene and reproduce it in a way that we can see the very bright and the very dark details in the actual scene using our limited display technologies that have a much more limited dynamic range.

It's not a whole lot different than when Ansel Adams used the zone system to capture up to 14 stops of dynamic range on his negatives and then squeeze all of that information onto papers that were capable of only 6-8 stops of dynamic range.

In other words, we're fitting the *high dynamic range* of a scene into our *low dynamic range* display technologies. Thus the end result of HDRI is a low dynamic range image that includes as many details as possible from a high dynamic range scene.

Comment: But it's also true that in an HDR you can see more details on the shadows or highlights. This means that you were able to reproduce more DR than with a single photo. I'd like to calculate this improvement.

Comment: You're not reproducing more dynamic range. You're reducing the dynamic range between the brightest and darkest parts of the image. You're still bound by the limits of your display technology's dynamic range.

Comment: yes sure, but I'm not talking about the display dynamic range. I'm talking about what the photo can capture more. If a HDR photo have more details both in shadows and highlight (that were clipped in the original photo), this means that there's some more data in that photo, that I could capture more details of the scene in one time. I was wondering how to quantify this.

Comment: If an HDR photo has more details that can be recovered, it wasn't clipped in the original image(s), it was clipped when that raw data was converted to a viewable image. How to quantify this? You test the camera and see how many stops of DR it is able to capture between the noise floor and full well capacity. There are plenty of online resources that have already done that for many cameras. You then use a light meter with a very narrow angle to meter the brightest and darkest details in a scene you wish to capture, and compare that to the results of the sensor/camera test.

Comment: This will tell you if you can capture it with a single raw exposure, or if you will need multiple exposures and if so, over what total dynamic range.

Comment: So the only way to do this is to do some measurements in a lab I guess

Comment: The only way to find the maximum DR a camera is capable of (with raw data) is to measure it precisely. The only way to find the total DR of a scene is to meter it precisely. Those two things will rarely be the same. Sometimes the camera is capable of capturing a wider DR than the scene provides. Sometimes the scene has a wider DR than the camera is capable of capturing.

Comment: I added a photo to try to explain better the problem

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, an 8bit jpeg is 24bit color; 8bits per color. Your 32bit HDR is also 8bit per color plus an additional 8bit shared channel (Alpha).

Secondly, not every correctly exposed image will have values from min (black/0) to max (white/255). HDR is rewriting values to fit w/in the display/reproduction capability... if in that process it eliminates any true blacks or whites that exist in the original then the result will be a reduced DR.

You are not wanting to measure the difference between min/max, that will always be the same due to the limitations of reproduction/display. What you want to measure is the difference in the number of steps/values that exist *in between* min and max.

I.e. an image that only has black and white values only contains two stops of dynamic range. Whereas an image that has black, white, and mid grey has three stops (values) of DR displayed within the image; even though black and white are equally as far apart.
The greatest increases in displayed DR occur in the darkest parts of an image, where small differences in tonal values still equals a stop of luminance.

Comment: When I calculate the HDR dynamic range I use the original radiance map, where every pixel value is the actual luminance. I'm not using a tonemapped image. But sometimes the DR still decreases.

Comment: anyone, I added a photo to try to explain better the problem

Comment: What tool are you using to measure the luminance values? In any case, you can only measure the luminance values *as recorded*; and in no case can they ever be more/less than what the camera sensor is capable of. I.e. you shift and blend exposures so that the scene's DR fits w/in the limited DR capability of the sensor and display... you are *compressing* the scene's DR.

Comment: yeah I compress the DR when I tone map the radiance map to an RGB photo. But a radiance map contains an higher dynamic range than a tone mapped HDR photo and also more than a single exposure photo

Comment: The radiance map is generated from the recorded images, and the recorded images cannot contain more DR than the sensor is capable of recording. So the combined image cannot contain more DR than the sensor is capable of recording. Your darkest exposure records brighter areas w/o clipping, but drives more dark areas below measurable (clipped black). And the opposite is true of you brightest exposure (more areas clipped white). There is never a difference between the min and max recordable/displayable... what you are doing is increasing the number of steps in-between.

Comment: Yes I understand that the sensor dynamic range is the absolute maximum dynamic range, but a single jpg photo cannot reach that dynamic range (I think). If you have a look at this presentation, maybe you'll understand a little better how I imagine the things in my mind (should be from page 13 to 18) https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs448a-10/hdr-bilateral-26jan10-opt.pdf

Comment: No, a jpeg can contain more than 8stops DR... it depends on the gamma curve (non-linear conversion) applied to the (linear) raw data when creating the jpeg. This is very similar to LR's displaying the raw data in the Melissa profile with a modified 2.2 gamma curve (ProPhoto color space with sRGB tone curve applied) as opposed to ProPhotos native gamma of 1 (which is what is used for the calculations/processing). The fairly standard 2.2 gamma curve is used because it most closely replicates human vision... the 2.2 gamma ends at around 11-12 stops of DR.

Comment: The HDR conversions use contrast reduction and gamma compression prior to display/output with the 2.2 gamma curve applied.

Answer (score -2):

Ok I think I found a solution by myself. I'll try to explain it here, let me know what you people think about it.

**INPUT**: 3 grayscale 8 bit images

**OUTPUT**: 1 HDR radiance map (single precision)

So, to compute the HDR image I use the [Devebec algorithm](http://www.pauldebevec.com/Research/HDR/debevec-siggraph97.pdf)

This algorithm outputs the radiance map computed from the 3 (or more) input photos. Every pixel value represent the relative illuminance (irradiance actually) of the corresponding point in the scene. I can then calculate the dynamic range simply by using the max and min pixel value from this matrix:

```
stops = log2(max) - log2(min);
```

It's not important that the irradiance values are not the absolute one, because we are computing a range:

```
absolute_value = scale_factor + relative_value

range = absolute_max - absolute_min = (relative_max + scale_factor) - (relative_min + scale_factor) = relative_max - relative_min
```

To blend the images the algorithm need to recover the camera response function. This function relate the pixel values to the relative illuminance of the scene. This means that once I have the camera response curve, and the maximum and minimum pixel value in the original image (in this case 0 and 255) I can retrieve the relative irradiance values of the original image too:

```
exp(g(255)-ln⁡(dt) ) = E_max
exp(g(0)-ln⁡(dt) ) = E_min
```

where

```
g = inverse of camera response function (calculated by the script)
dt = shutter speed used on the original image
```

I can then compute the actual dynamic range of the original image and compare it to the HDR image dynamic range.

Yet, seems like some images lose DR when blended together. So I'm a little confused. 
For example, [these images](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3fdcd2e260e168265f5a7d5fa08a1d5e20191008160449/1f11a93459fb994c4f113f6f991aa6dc20191008160449/7498e5) once blended have narrower DR than before.

Comment: I like that people are downvoting this without giving an explanation of what they don't like about this reasoning

Comment: Assuming the resulting image has some values that are at both min and max (0-255), and that the script determines the response curve based upon the visible image as displayed, then the formula is essentially taking DXO's Tonality measurement for the sensor (DR corrected for noise) and adding the exposure shift. I.e. for the A7RIII at base ISO the sensors capability is ~ 9bits (stops) + a 3 stop exposure shift between images for two additional images (6stops) ='s a 15stop calculated DR.

Comment: If instead your min value is 10 (which still appears black) you will have lost ~4 stops of DR in the resulting image.

Comment: Well if my min value is 10 and I've lost 4 stops that's ok, if it's actually what happened in the image. 
About DXO mark they use another equation to calculate the DR: they use the black noise level (taken from the left black band on Canons) and it's standard deviation. Also this is done with the RAW picture

Comment: DXO's Tonality measure is corrected for noise, their DR measure is not. It's the difference between what others call "photographic/usable DR" and "engineering DR." Everything starts from the raw data...